# Clicking a QComboBox in a QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget, qcombobox

I have a table of QComboBox Widgets in a QTableWidget.
I've noticed a slight different in their behavior. Normally a QComboBox on a click anywhere, will open the drop down menu. However, when embedded in the TableWidget, it requires a precise click off the dropdown arrow. A click on the text of the combobox will not activate the dropdown.

Is there a way to extend the normal behavior when within the table? I'm assuming whats happening is on click I'm actually selecting a parent widget instead of the QComboBox, thus not dropping down on a click anywhere.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that behavior. The combobox still expands when I click on the text. Can you provide a minimal example.

Comment: @NgocMinhNguyen can you paste how you did it?

Comment: This is how I did it. https://pastebin.com/4sAubyAY. There is nothing anywhere else. Tested on Windows with Qt 5.15.1 MinGW 32-bit